# Proxmox - backup OpenVZ on NFS

Tags: nfs, openvz, proxmox

I'm using Proxmox 3.2 with OpenVZ containers and I'm trying to setup a backup system for my 2 nodes cluster.

I created a NFS share on a Debian 7.5 server (not under Proxmox, and not inside the cluster).

/etc/exports:

```
/share/           node-1(rw,no_root_squash,subtree_check,sync)
/share/           node-2(rw,no_root_squash,subtree_check,sync)
```

I added it to the cluster:

[image]

Then I created the backup job:

[image]

When it's time to backup I only find these logs on the NFS share:

```
Aug 06 01:40:01 INFO: Starting Backup of VM 100 (openvz)
Aug 06 01:40:01 INFO: CTID 100 exist mounted running
Aug 06 01:40:01 INFO: status = running
Aug 06 01:40:01 INFO: backup mode: snapshot
Aug 06 01:40:01 INFO: ionice priority: 7
Aug 06 01:40:01 INFO: creating lvm snapshot of /dev/mapper/system-root ('/dev/system/vzsnap-node-1-0')
Aug 06 01:40:01 INFO:   Volume group "system" has insufficient free space (0 extents): 256 required.
Aug 06 01:40:01 ERROR: Backup of VM 100 failed - command 'lvcreate --size 1024M --snapshot --name vzsnap-node-1-0 /dev/system/root' failed: exit code 5
```

What is wrong with this configuration?

Comment: maybe you because you are trying to create a volume snapshot without any free space

Comment: Where exactly do I need free space ? On the proxmox node ?

Comment: i don't use promox, but in the errorlog you posted abobe, i seen this "Aug 06 01:40:01 INFO: creating lvm snapshot of /dev/mapper/system-root ('/dev/system/vzsnap-node-1-0')
Aug 06 01:40:01 INFO:   Volume group "system" has insufficient free space (0 extents): 256 required.", maybe this happen because the backup mode is snapshot, so promox try to create a snapshot of your lvm volumes

Comment: Well, it's strange, and I don't really know what to do to make it work.

Comment: if you try to use vzdump <containerid> --dumpdir /yournfsmountpoint ? for information about lvm snapbackup http://openvz.org/Backup_of_a_running_container_with_vzdump

Comment: It looks like I need a LVM volume if I want to do live backup, and mine has no free space.

Answer (score 2):

You have to free space on the LVM root volume. You'll have to reboot your server in rescue mode in order to do it (as it's the root volume)

Proxmox is trying to dump the LVM volume of the container and it has no free space on the LVM root volume to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is correct, you have however selected snapshot, which is zero-downtime container backup. Seemingly your LVM however isn't setup correctly so the snapshot can't be done. I would recommend to try with suspend mode. (which has very little downtime)